# Qualtrics task is working slow

Tags: qualtrics

I use codes in qualtrics in order to have a task.

The task is working very slow. I have been told this is because I use the same code in every slide.. Is there any option to use the code once?

Thank you
This are the codes I use every page:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{

$('NextButton').hide();
this.hideNextButton();
var that = this;
Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
  var choiceID = null;
  switch (e.keyCode) {
  case 90: // z' was pressed
  choiceID = 1;
  break;
case 77: // 'm' was pressed
  choiceID = 2;
  break;
  }

  if (choiceID) {
Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
that.clickNextButton();
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in the survey header or footer, but it wouldn't speed it up. It would still load and run exactly the same way.

The first two lines of your script are redundant.  Remove the first line.  Also, you should use addOnReady instead of addOnload whenever you are referencing the PreviousButton or NextButton.